# Newton's Third Law and energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, conservation-laws

Consider this situation : A person and an object are standing on an ice floor ( or any frictionless surface for that matter ). If the person pushes the object, the object moves forward and the person moves in the opposite direction. Now the object moves forward because the energy was transferred from the person to the object. However from where does the person get the energy to move in the opposite direction?

Note: the same question can be modelled as a person pushing boat backwards and person moving forward, just in case my question was unclear. Pardon my language.

Comment: From the man himself...

Comment: The work expended by the person is just distributed between the object's and the person's kinetic energy.

Comment: From his breakfast.

Comment: You could just as easily ask,  where do you get the energy to walk or run?  You are pushing yourself forward when your shoe meets the pavement. As @garyp succinctly puts it, the ultimate energy source  comes from your food intake

Comment: @CountTo10  ... or nuclear reactions in the sun ...

Answer (score 2):

The person got the energy from his "biochemistry". ATP molecules present in the muscles provide energy to perform activities. Therefore the object gains energy from the person's biochemistry. It got nothing to do with newton's law in terms of energy. However you can apply the  "momentum conservation" to describe motions.

Comment: But the energy of the person is converted into kinetic energy of the object. From where does the person himself get the kinetic energy to accelerate in opposite direction? 

If you say that the person's energy is divided into kinetic energy of the object and the person himself,  can you please explain the process in detail? If possible please explain me what happens at molecular level.

Comment: Okay well, he gets food and the energy stored in chemical bonds in foods is stored in his body, in ATP in his cells (again as chemical energy). This is basically how he gets energy at the first place. Then through muscles, this energy is transferred to him self (for his backward movement) and to the object that he throws (for its forward movement). Therefore if you assume that there is no energy lost (as heat for example), the chemical energy stored in the ATP is completely converted in to the kinetic energy of the object plus himself.